# Why does 'cd' not work on an entry with 'directory' attribute?

Tags: linux, fedora, root, chmod

My OS is fedora 20. I act as a root user.

under / directory, I input:

```
#ll
...
d????????? ? ? ? ? mnt
...

#cd mnt
bash: cd: mnt: Not a directory

#chmod 777 mnt
chmod: cannot access 'mnt': No such file or directory
```

What's the root cause of such a weird problem?

Comment: what directory are you in?  You may need to 'cd /mnt'

Comment: I'm under the root directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `?`s in the output of `ls -l` are that what it really says, then you most-likely have a filesystem mounted to `/mnt` that is no more (removed USB stick, bus-failure, f*cked up filesystem, …).  You'll have to `umount` the filesystem to get things straight again.

If you just mounted the filesystem and this is the result, try `fsck`ing the filesystem (after `umount`, of course).

If there's no filesystem mounted to `/mnt` and this is the *real* `/mnt` directory on your `/`-fs, then get a live rescue CD, check your filesystems and pray.